# How is the probability sign taken out of equation

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble understanding the following text:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P\left( \left|\frac{\hat I_n - I}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \right| \leq a \right) = \int_{-a}^a \gamma(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = \textrm{erf}(a/\sqrt{2})$$
Therefore, for large $n$, it hold with probability approximately $(1 - \alpha)$ that
$$|\hat I_n - I| \leq \left(\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \, \sqrt{2} \textrm{erf}^{-1}(1 - \alpha)
 $$

I simply don't understand what transformation was applied to show that this results hold. Can anybody explain to me how the $\mathbb P$ was taken out and how did they know that the result holds for probability approximately $(1 - \alpha)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P\left( \left|\frac{\hat I_n - I}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \right| \leq a \right) = \textrm{erf}(a/\sqrt{2})
$$
then for large $n$
$$
\mathbb P\left( \left|\frac{\hat I_n - I}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \right| \leq a \right) \approx \textrm{erf}(a/\sqrt{2}).
$$
Take right expression equal to $1-\alpha$: 
$$
\textrm{erf}(a/\sqrt{2}) = 1-\alpha \quad \iff \quad a/\sqrt{2} = \textrm{erf}^{-1}(1 - \alpha) \quad \iff \quad a = \sqrt{2}\,\textrm{erf}^{-1}(1 - \alpha). 
$$
Then for large $n$ 
$$
\mathbb P\left( \left|\frac{\hat I_n - I}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \right| \leq \sqrt{2}\,\textrm{erf}^{-1}(1 - \alpha) \right) \approx 1-\alpha
$$
or
$$
\mathbb P\left( \left|{\hat I_n - I} \right| \leq \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{2}\,\textrm{erf}^{-1}(1 - \alpha) \right) \approx 1-\alpha
$$
This is exactly what is written: for large $n$, it hold with **probability** approximately $(1−\alpha)$ that inequality under probability sign holds.